# Adicionar ícone na Activity Bar VSCODE

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Estou no VSCode e o ícone do git hub não aparece na activity bar. alguém sabe como colocar o ícone do git lá novamente?

[image: d]

Comment: Já tive esse problema, e não lembro como resolvi rss, mas lembro que tem a ver com o Source Control, vc pode ver sobre isso aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609255/git-missing-in-vs-code-no-source-control-providers e aqui na doc oficial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol

Comment: vai nessa mesm barra onde está os icones em um lugar vazio e pressione o botão direito do mouse, e selecione o icone perdido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ícone que você procura é referente à extensão nativa do VSCode e ele pode ter desaparecido se tal extensão nativa estiver desabilitada. Para fazer essa verificação siga os passos:

1. Selecione o ícone de extensões no canto direito da tela
   [image]
2. Clique no filtro de pesquisas e selecione a opção de ***Built-in***
   [image]
   [image]
3. Pesquise pela extensão "Git" e tenha certeza de que o filtro ***@builtin*** esteja aplicado
   [image]
4. Verifique se alguma das extensões está desabilitada, caso esteja habilite-a novamente, e feche e abra o VSCode novamente para ter certeza de que a modificação foi aplicada